# Are the gitlab pipeline log output a log file or actual streamed log which we see in the terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've a gitlab job which runs a script which will print out some logs in following manner:

```js
const readline = require('readline');

process.stdout.write("Hello World");
readline.clearLine(process.stdout);
readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0);
process.stdout.write("Hello World Again!!!");
```

The expected output is like:
**Hello World Again!!!**

But gitlab pipeline logs shows this instead:
**Hello WorldHello World Again!!!**

I suspect that this is because the gitlab pipeline output is a log file storing each stdout output and showing it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no actual log file used on the runner side, but the effect is similar. Output is streamed to GitLab in near-realtime and all parts are concatenated by the GitLab server (then also stored in a file). When you try to do this:

```
readline.clearLine(process.stdout);
readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0);
```

In a TTY, like your local terminal, this will effectively cause the next message to write over the first one.

However, this has no impact on GitLab's output because stdout is not a TTY in this case -- there is no cursor to move and scripts cannot control the pointer -- meaning previous items which have already been emitted to stdout will appear in the job log, even if you use methods to try to clear the log that normally work in a terminal setting.

Comment: Thank you @sytech for explaining this. Do you know any approach to achieve overwriting the log or is it just simple not possible in this case?